# Свой адрес для модального окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

На сайте модалки с прописанными идентификаторами. Требуется сделать им свои "адреса". Что бы человек вбил этот адрес и модалка была открыта. 
Ну как бы задать им якоря...

Окна в Joomla! на Uikit.

Как я понимаю тут через JS можно сделать. Но вот не силён.

Подскажите пожалуйста варианты?

Comment: что за _модалки с прописанными идентификаторами_? Что используется для показа? какая-то библиотека или самописное что-то?

Comment: Модалки на joomla!. Показываются по data-uk-modal="{target:'#my-id2081'}". Просто меняется стиль с display:none на block.

Comment: Судя по атрибуту используется [uikit](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/modal.html). У него есть апи для показа скрытия модального окна. Нужно просто при загрузке проверить адрес и показать нужное окно

Comment: Да, действительно Uikit. Ничего не слышал про эту библиотеку. Но дело в том что при открытии окна адрес страницы никак не меняется.

Comment: А как можно передавать в адрес страницы id открытого модального окна?

Comment: Например менять `hash`, по событию открытия попапа

Comment: Да, именно так я и думаю. Не знаю как реализовать...

Comment: по ссылке выше, которую я дал есть описание событий. Там  есть событие открытия и событие закрытия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, как-то так:

```
let ancor = location.hash.substr(1);
let modal;
if(ancor === "my-id2081"){
    //$('#my-id2081').show(); //Для любой модалки
    modal = UIkit.modal("#my-id2081");
    modal.show(); //Для UiKit
}
```

Универсальный вариант:

```
let ancor = '#'+location.hash.substr(1);
let modal;
if($(ancor).length){
    modal = UIkit.modal(ancor);
    modal.show();      
}
```

Comment: Когда окно открывается, адрес не меняется. Это код в данном случае поможет?

Comment: @Григорий, вы же изначально не указали, что за модалка. Для UiKit дописал, при открытии ссылки так точно модалка должна открыться.

Comment: ого, спасибо! Да, всё работает. Получается для других модалок мне просто нужно продублировать данный код с заменой id?

Comment: а возможен какой-то универсальный код? Что бы не прописывать на каждое окно JS? Массив данных со всеми модалками, и в условии перебор этого массива, и если совпадает, то выполнять.

Comment: @Григорий, добавил к ответу, так можно открывать вообще любые модалки по якорю.

Comment: всё таки понимаю, что требуется ещё при открытии модалки передавать в url его id. Это как я понимаю труднее реализовать?

Comment: @Григорий, задайте отдельный вопрос, потому что он уже отличается от текущей темы